# Calling base class in callback for ES6 in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

For example I have the following class:

```
class X extends Y
{
   constructor() {  super(); } 

   method() {
      asyncMethod( function( err ) {   
          super.method( err );
      } );
    }
}
```

However,  `super` is not the base class `Y`. How can I pass `super` to that callback?

Is there any solution than using arrow functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use arrow functions, e.g.,

```
asyncMethod( err => super.method( err ) );
```

Comment: Note that depending on the implementation of `asyncMethod` this code can behave differently (since it returns).

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go with **arrow functions** but, if you need an alternative, here it goes.

According to JavaScript closures behaviour, you can **store a reference to** `super.method` **in a variable** and use it within the callback.

Here's the code:

```
class X extends Y
{
   constructor() {  super(); } 

   method() {
      let superMethod = super.method;

      asyncMethod(function (err) {   
          superMethod(err);
      });
   }
}
```